# Make relations correctly in Greendao to get inner entities

Tags: android, database, entities, greendao

I parse response from server and save it to database (greendao). All objects saved correctly. For example I have the entities:

```
@Entity(active = true, nameInDb = "PURCHASE")
public class Purchase {
    private long purchaseShopId;
    private String createdAt;
    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "shopId")
    private List<ShopStats> shopStats;
 // ...

@Entity(active = true, nameInDb = "SHOP_STATS")
public class ShopStats {
    private long shopId;
    @ToOne
    private Shop shop;
    @ToOne
    private Spend spend;
 // ...

@Entity(active = true, nameInDb = "SHOP_STATS_SPEND")
public class Spend {
    private long shopId;
    @SerializedName("sum")
    private float paymentSum;
    @SerializedName("discount_sum")
    private float discountSum;
// ...
```

And when i want to fetch all Purchase:

```
List<Purchase> purchasesList = getDaoSession().getPurchaseDao().loadAll();
```

I excpected to give all inner objects: ShopStats, Spend, Shop - like:

```
Spend spend = purchasesList.get(i).getShopSatats().getSpend(); // in cycle
```

But here I get null. What can I do to fetch inner objects like this?

I suspect need fix my annotation to bind inner objects but until it does not worked. I tried fix annotations like this `@ToOne(joinProperty = "shopId")` but it produce exception:

`If @ToOne with foreign property used, @Column and @Unique are ignored`

Please give me advice how I can achieve this? Or I can only get each list objects separately from DaoSession?

Answer (score 0):

Just to recap,
Inside each `Purchase` there are several `ShopStats` because I can see in your `Purchase` data model that there is a list of `ShopStats` and it's having one-to-many relationship with `Purchase`

`@ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "shopId")
    private List<ShopStats> shopStats;`

So I think your code `purchasesList.get(i)` returns you a `Purchase` object.

Then `purchasesList.get(i).getShopSatats()` will return you a `List<ShopStats>` and NOT a single `Shopstats`

Then inside each `Shopstats` there is one `Spend`

So you need to specify which `Shopstats`'s `Spend` you want to fetch.

Hints :

- Maybe you can modify your code as

`Spend spend = purchasesList.get(i).getShopSatats().get(j).getSpend(); // in cycle`

- Maybe you should rename your Entity class `Shopstats` to `Shopstat` and your `List<Shopstats> shopStats` in `Purchase` to `List<Shopstat> shopStats`. My point is make sure Shopstats and List of Shopstats have names which make sense and is easily understandable.

I am beginner, let me know your feedbacks and I'll be glad to help you if need any more help*